# Problem when trying to build debian packages

Tags: 18.04, dpkg, make, debian

Hei,

I am trying to build a package using make command and I get the following error:

```
  dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (used by debian/sgx-aesm-service/opt/intel/sgx-aesm-
  service/aesm/bundles/liblinux_network_service_bundle.so) Hint: check if the library
    actually comes from a package. dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/sgx-aesm-service.substvars
   -l/home/kleir/linux-sgx/build/linux debian/sgx-aesm-service/opt/intel/sgx-aesm-service/aesm/liboal.so debian/sgx-aesm-service/opt/intel/sgx-aesm-service/aesm/aesm_service 
debian/sgx-aesm-service/opt/intel/sgx-aesm-service/aesm/liburts_internal.so debian/sgx-aesm-service/opt/intel/sgx-aesm-service/aesm/bundles/
 liblinux_network_service_bundle.so debian/sgx-
aesm-service/opt/intel/sgx-aesm-service/aesm/libipc.so debian/sgx-aesm- 
service/opt/intel/sgx-aesm-service/aesm/libutils.so debian/sgx-aesm-service/opt/intel/sgx- 
aesm-service/aesm/libCppMicroServices.so.4.0.0 returned exit code 2 dh_shlibdeps:
Aborting due to earlier error debian/rules:11: recipe for target 'override_dh_shlibdeps' 
failed make[2]: *** [override_dh_shlibdeps] Error 255 make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kleir/linux-sgx/linux/installer/deb/sgx-aesm-service/sgx-aesm-service-2.10.100.2
' debian/rules:8: recipe for target 'binary' failed make[1]: *** [binary] Error 2 make[1]:   
Leaving directory '/home/kleir/linux-sgx/linux/installer/deb/sgx-aesm-service/sgx-aesm-service-2.10.100.2' 
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit 
status 2 Makefile:123: recipe for target 'deb_sgx_aesm_service' failed make: *** [deb_sgx_aesm_service] Error 2
```

The problem comes from debian package of sgx-aesm-service and I checked the `rule` file and it looked like:

```
 1  #!/usr/bin/make -f
 2  # -*- makefile -*-
   
 3  # Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
 4  #export DH_VERBOSE=1
   
 5  %:
 6      dh $@
   
 7  override_dh_shlibdeps:
 8      dh_shlibdeps -l $(LINUX_BUILD_DIR)
```

I tried to midfy this file into :

```
 1  #!/usr/bin/make -f
 2  # -*- makefile -*-
   
 3  # Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
 4  #export DH_VERBOSE=1
   
 5  %:
 6      dh $@
   
 7  override_dh_shlibdeps:
 8      dh_shlibdeps --dpkg-shlibdeps-params=--ignore-missing-info
```

and I still get the same error as above. My distribution is `ubuntu18.04`

I have installed `libcrypto.so.1.1` when I installed **openssl** but also bby running the command below:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

with `sudo` permission.

I am trying to solve that problem for more than a day now but could not find any solution which is relevant to my problem. Is there any solution which can help me solve that problem?